# 301 htaccess redirect everything but existing pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, forward

I want to move from http to https on the same server. All pages, files, etc. need to be forwarded to https, all but four pages that are embedded on several websites using an iFrame. Since https can't be included in a `iframe`, i want to leave those but add everything else.

I am playing with htaccess for over an hour now, but without success. Latest trial is below. But in this example, i need to write the files down myself. I would like to forward everything that doesn't exist on the `http` server anymore to the `https` server and leave the rest as it is.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} = off
RewriteCond $1 !^(inschrijven-frame|inschrijven-frame2)\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.url.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What needs to be done is:

1. If the file is on http open it.
2. If the file is not on http, goto https, so http://www.url.com/test.php automatically becomes https://www.urlcom/test.php
3. Pages that are not found on 2, should be forwarded to de main domain on https

Comment: **1)** This line is wrong `RewriteCond %{HTTP} =on` -- it should be `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [NC]` **2)** You are using wrong character for OR regex logic -- should be `|` instead of `¦`.

Comment: Thanks LazyOne, do you also have a suggestion to not go to https if the http file is there?

Comment: Use this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` . Explanation/Documentation is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it's not working, see updated post.

Comment: @LazyOne if you post an answer i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved it. Is this okay?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|test1|test2)\.php$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ipage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

@LazyOne if you post an answer i can accept it.